# How Kaniko images be built and pushed to AWS ECR via Jenkins pipelines

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials, amazon-ecr, kaniko

I get an empty preload of credentials when trying to push the kaniko image to AWS ECR

loaded credentials that populate and push the kaniko image to AWS ECR